# Oracle/general sql - are all where conditions always checked?

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause, sql-function

There's a query which does something like this:

```
select * from cars c where c.WheelCount > 0 or CountWheels(c) > 0
```

Is the function `CountWheels` called for every row, or just for those rows where `t.Count <= 0` ?

The thing is that that function contains logic that should be executed every time -- very likely a bad design; it's part of code of which I have very little control.

This is a simplified example, and I cannot just write `select * from cars c where CountWheels(c.Body) > 0` since that would remove some data. Think of it as: give me all cars that ever had wheels, even though some of them may have 0 wheels right now.

Comment: Oracle will *probably* call the function only on rows where `WheelCount <= 0` or `NULL`.  It has a pretty good optimizer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the function CountWheels called for every row, or just for those rows where t.Count <= 0 ?

In general, you don’t get to choose this. SQL is a descriptive language, as opposed to a procedural language: you specify the results you want, and you trust the optimizer to pick the best possible execution plan.

You *might* try to influence the database with a `case` expression, which gives more control over the execution flow:

```
where case 
    when c.WheelCount   > 0 then 1
    when CountWheels(c) > 0 then 1
end = 1
```

Comment: "that function contains logic that should be executed every time" - so as case short-circuits, don't you need the searched conditions in reverse order?

Comment: Thanks for the answer GMB! And thanks for the reply @alex-poole because these two I can do in my environment, and the problem is resolved!